# Let $T$ be a Hermitian operator and $\|v\|=1$, prove $\langle T^2(v),v\rangle \ge\langle T(v),v\rangle^2$

Tags: inner-products

Let $T$ be a Hermitian operator on an inner product space $V$ over the field of complex numbers, $C$ (of a finite dimension), also assume $\|v\|=1$. Prove:

$$\langle T^2(v),v\rangle \ge\langle T(v),v\rangle^2$$

Comment: Here's a (somewhat off-topic) tip: you can use the `\langle` and `\rangle` commands to print the $\langle$ and $\rangle$ angled brackets with proper spacing; `<` and `>` are the less-than and greater-than operators, so LaTeX spaces them differently.

Comment: @Aeolian thanks, it's indeed looks better :)

Comment: Also `\|` for the norm rather than `||`.

Comment: It is true for every $\|v\|\leq 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: As pointed out by Robert Israel, this follows immediately from Cauchy-Schwarz. I so wanted to use your (wrong and now deleted hint), that I actually basically reproved Cauchy-Schwarz...

Develop the following
$$
((T-\alpha I)^2v,v)=\alpha^2\|v\|^2-2\alpha(Tv,v)+(T^2v,v).
$$
Note that for every $\alpha\in \mathbb{R}$, the operator $(T-\alpha I)^2=(T-\alpha I)^*(T-\alpha I) $ is hermitian positive so
$$
((T-\alpha I)^2v,v)\geq 0.
$$

We have a quadratic in $\alpha$ which is always nonnegative.

This means that its discriminant is nonpositive:
$$
\Delta=4((Tv,v)^2-(T^2v,v)\|v\|^2)\leq 0.
$$
Hence
$$
(Tv,v)^2\leq (T^2v,v)\|v\|^2.
$$

So your inequality holds for all $\|v\|\leq 1$.

Comment: @User Do you need more details?

Comment: I finally understand it, I accepted your answer. I would still like to know how to prove/use the hint

Comment: @User Where did you get this hint? It is wrong. For instance, if $T=Id$ and $\|v\|=1$, you have $\alpha =1$ and the hint says: $0=1$.

Comment: Oh well... after reading your answer I was under the impression that the hint is wrong. I received it in a test :(

Comment: I removed the hint from the question, thanks

Comment: @User You're welcome.

Answer (score 3):

It's not true as stated, because it has the wrong scaling behaviour with respect to $v$.
Were you supposed to assume $\|v\|=1$?

EDIT: With that assumption, the hint is overkill.  The result follows directly from Cauchy-Schwarz.  Note that $\langle T^2 v, v \rangle = \langle T v, T v \rangle$ since $T$ is Hermitian.

Comment: Oh, you're right, I missed it, I'll update the question